# The account I used to create API Keys is gone. Transfer the key to another account?

Tags: api, key, google-apps, credentials

My company uses Google Apps-For-Domains, but syncs it with Microsoft Active Director.

My application used Google API keys/creds generated for a user in our AD. The keys/creds are fine, but the other day we deleted the user from our AD, so it no longer exists in our Google-Apps-For-Domains. It's not just disabled, it's gone. Can't find the user at all.

So our backup plan is to create a new user and create new API keys/creds, but this may break things for us. We're hoping there's a better way...

----> Any way to transfer Google API keys/creds to a new Google user? Without creating new API keys/creds?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm curious if it's possible to move google API credentials between accounts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer existing Android app map key to another developer account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336210/transfer-existing-android-app-map-key-to-another-developer-account)