# Transfer existing Android app map key to another developer account?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-console-developer

I'm working on an android application for my company.In this application Map key, GCM and GOOGLE+ are created under my own developer console account.Now the application on store.

Now they want to transfer the app to the companies own developer console account , will users still receives GCM notifications,google map and Google+ integration as previous ?

Have any way to transfer same map key and GCM key  to new account without make any issues for users who already installed the application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was once in a similar situation and just added the person or persons that will be in charge of it as owners of the project in the console.

Menu > Permissions

[image: Developer Console]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Is it possible to delete the application from the previous account after give permission to new person?

Comment: the project must have at least one owner, once you invite other user as an owner and they accepted the invitation you can remove yourself from the members then you will have no connection to the project, unless the current owner invites you again