# Transfer Google API keys to another account

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-cloud-messaging, google-developers-console

I am transferring one of my published application to another Google account(which is possible), but i cant find anywhere how to transfer the API keys associated with old account to new account for application.

As this is old application and use GCM also and had many app users, so I want to keep my existing keys.

Any help please?

Answer (score 4):

As stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336210/transfer-existing-android-app-map-key-to-another-developer-account), just add the person or persons that will be in charge of it as owners of the project in the Developers Console. *Once you invite other user as an owner and they accepted the invitation, you can remove yourself from the members then you will have no connection to the project.* Here's a related post: [How to transfer google cloud project ownership?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697766/how-to-transfer-google-cloud-project-ownership)